# How to use table type in T-SQL dynamically

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, exec

I want to create a stored procedure with dynamic parameters. One of these parameters is a table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdTable] AS TABLE ([Id] [int] NULL)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_deleteCells]
    @table IdTable READONLY,
    @tableName NVARCHAR(50),
    @fieldName NVARCHAR(50),
    @result BIT OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500);

    SET @SQL='delete from TBL_CustomerTerminal where ID in (select ID from @table)'
    EXEC (@SQL);

    SET @result = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

How can I exec this code without errors?? Right now, I get:

> Must declare the table variable "@table"

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here at all? Just run the delete statement and forget the dynamic sql.

Comment: it was dynamiclly at all but i replace static field for work certainly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete from TBL_CustomerTerminal where ID in (select ID from @table)'
  , N'@table dbo.IdTable readonly'  /* parameter declaration for sp_executesql */
  , @table /* pass the parameters */
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you need dynamic SQL for the query above. But I assume it is just a sample.

The dynamic SQL query has it's own code visibility. It can't see any variable outside of the locally defined variables. If you want to pass parameters to your query you need to use sp_executesql instead of EXEC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql